# SQL - Remove select non-alphanumeric characters from a string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to sanitize strings in my company's databases (from the early days before we had better data validation). However, the function isn't working. I figured out that it's only assigning '[' to the @Pattern string, but I'm not sure why.

Code to re-create the function *(you'll need to add your DB prefix before the function name)*:

```
/* Remove select non-alphanumeric characters from a string */

CREATE FUNCTION [CleanString] (@Str VARCHAR(max))

RETURNS VARCHAR(max) AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @BadIndex SMALLINT, -- Index of bad character
        @Pattern CHAR(132)  -- Characters to look for (min length is # chars + 4 for %[]% enclosing)

SELECT @Pattern = 
'%['
    /* +CHAR(00) */ +CHAR(01) +CHAR(02) +CHAR(03) +CHAR(04) +CHAR(05) +CHAR(06) +CHAR(07) +CHAR(08) +CHAR(09) 
    +CHAR(10) +CHAR(11) +CHAR(12) +CHAR(13) +CHAR(14) +CHAR(15) +CHAR(16) +CHAR(17) +CHAR(18) +CHAR(19) 
    +CHAR(20) +CHAR(21) +CHAR(22) +CHAR(23) +CHAR(24) +CHAR(25) +CHAR(26) +CHAR(27) +CHAR(28) +CHAR(29) 
    +CHAR(30) +CHAR(31) /* +CHAR(32) */ +CHAR(33) +CHAR(34) +CHAR(35) +CHAR(36) /* +CHAR(37) */ +CHAR(38) +CHAR(39) 
    +CHAR(40) +CHAR(41) +CHAR(42) +CHAR(43) +CHAR(44) +CHAR(45) /* +CHAR(46) */ +CHAR(47) /* +CHAR(48) +CHAR(49) 
    +CHAR(50) +CHAR(51) +CHAR(52) +CHAR(53) +CHAR(54) +CHAR(55) +CHAR(56) +CHAR(57) */ +CHAR(58) +CHAR(59) 
    +CHAR(60) +CHAR(61) +CHAR(62) +CHAR(63) /* +CHAR(64) +CHAR(65) +CHAR(66) +CHAR(67) +CHAR(68) +CHAR(69) 
    +CHAR(70) +CHAR(71) +CHAR(72) +CHAR(73) +CHAR(74) +CHAR(75) +CHAR(76) +CHAR(77) +CHAR(78) +CHAR(79) 
    +CHAR(80) +CHAR(81) +CHAR(82) +CHAR(83) +CHAR(84) +CHAR(85) +CHAR(86) +CHAR(87) +CHAR(88) +CHAR(89) 
    +CHAR(90)  +CHAR(91) */ +CHAR(92) /* +CHAR(93) */ +CHAR(94) /* +CHAR(95) */ +CHAR(96) /* +CHAR(97) +CHAR(98) +CHAR(99) 
    +CHAR(100) +CHAR(101) +CHAR(102) +CHAR(103) +CHAR(104) +CHAR(105) +CHAR(106) +CHAR(107) +CHAR(108) +CHAR(109) 
    +CHAR(110) +CHAR(111) +CHAR(112) +CHAR(113) +CHAR(114) +CHAR(115) +CHAR(116) +CHAR(117) +CHAR(118) +CHAR(119) 
    +CHAR(120) +CHAR(121) +CHAR(122) */ +CHAR(123) +CHAR(124) +CHAR(125) +CHAR(126) +CHAR(127) 
+']%',

@BadIndex = PATINDEX(@Pattern, @Str) -- Find first bad character index

WHILE @BadIndex > 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT 
             @Str = STUFF(@Str, @BadIndex, 1, ' ') -- Swap bad char for a space
            ,@BadIndex = PATINDEX(@Pattern, @Str) -- Find next bad character index
    END

RETURN @Str
END
```

Test *(you'll need to add your DB prefix before the function name)*:

```
select CleanString('woqp ienv8 90()*&@ #$! skllj_asdf') as test
```

Result:

```
'woqp ienv8 90()*&@ #$! skllj_asdf'
```

Thanks in advance for the help :)

Comment: Could it be that it is interpreting CHR(00) C-Style, as "end of string"? Try removing that first character only and start from CHR(1).

Comment: Char values 0 - 31 are control codes, meaning they are non-printable characters that are used to control peripherals such as printers.  Once you remove those, you should see more than just the initial '[' . As for your actual question, I'm not sure I follow you....your input and result are the exact same string.

Comment: Might be easier to create a table with the values you want to replace. Then create a table valued function that replaces a given character. You could then use a cross apply and sanitize all values in code that is more maintainable.

Comment: @JMK The goal was to strip out any invalid values that had made it into my records, leaving them with only alphanumeric and a few other characters (like @ or . for email addresses). The reason the test/result strings are the same is because the function doesn't work yet :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things I notice.  First, `@patindex` should have wildcards.  Second, you probably don't want to return inside the loop.

You can try logic like this:

```
SET @Pattern = '%' + @Pattern + '%';
SET @BadIndex = PATINDEX(@Pattern, @Str); -- Find first bad character index

WHILE @BadIndex > 0
    SELECT @Str = STUFF(@Str, @BadIndex, 1, ' '), -- Swap bad char for a space
           @BadIndex = PATINDEX(@Pattern, @Str); -- Find next bad character index
END;

RETURN @Str;
```

EDIT:

The problem is your `declare` statement.  You have declared the pattern to be `char()` instead of `varchar()`.  This means that the pattern is padded with spaces on the right, and the pattern never matches.

Just change this:

```
DECLARE @BadIndex SMALLINT, -- Index of bad character
        @Pattern CHAR(132)  -- Characters to look for (min length is # chars + 4 for %[]% enclosing)
```

To:

```
DECLARE @BadIndex SMALLINT, -- Index of bad character
        @Pattern VARCHAR(8000)  -- Characters to look for (min length is # chars + 4 for %[]% enclosing)
```

This time I tested it and it works.

Comment: I read that `patindex() ` acts as though it had wildcards included by default, but I explicitly added them to make sure. I also changed the bottom section of code to the above, but the result remains the same.

Comment: @zhespelt . . . It is easy enough to test `patindex()` with and without wildcards.  I usually find that I get different results.  In other databases, regular expressions don't usually require wildcards.